# pexpect for terminal at local computer

Tags: python, output, pexpect

I am developing codes user interaction using pexpect for the *local terminal* on *Mac* (not remote SSH) instead of using subprocess. But I don't know what did I do wrong with following cases to receive empty outputs:

1)

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
output = child.before
print output
```

The output is empty

2)

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ls -l')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
output = child.before
print output
```

It works well. The output is the list of files and folder just like we type ls -l at local terminal

3)

```
child = pexpect.spawn('pwd')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
output = child.before
print output
```

The output is empty

The output must be existing, not empty in 3 cases right? Do you know why 'ls' and 'pwd' are empty, but 'ls -l' is not? what should I do to fix 'empty' output?

Best regards,
Quyen Tran

Comment: Just checked on Ubuntu, all 3 scenarios work fine. And it must work the same way on any platform.

Comment: Thanks so much @alexanderlukanin13 I am using Macbook Pro OSX. Could you please let me know which version of pexpect you are using now? Regards, Quyen Tran

Comment: The latest version: `pexpect==4.2.1`

Comment: Hi there, I ran three cases with direct python prompt, three cases work well. Thanks, Quyen Tran

Answer (score 1):

For running commands which does not require an interaction, spawn is not the right method. It is better to use `pexpect.run` method and get the output as return value.

`pexpect.spawn` is more suited to spawn child process where you need to send commands and expect a response. Your code works fine on my terminal but if you aren't able to get it done on yours, use `run` method

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
0
print child.before
codes program.c << output of ls command
```